# AutoHotkey - Ignore the pressed key

Tags: autohotkey

I want my autohotkey script to have mouse clicks once i press shift+3 keys on my keyboard, ignoring the shift key being held down.

For example I have attempted it in this way:

```
   +3::
SetMouseDelay, 0
MouseGetPos, xpos, ypos
Send {Shift Up}
BlockInput, on
Send {Shift Up}
MouseClick, right, uhxpos, uhypos
Sleep, 41
MouseClick, left, yourxpos, yourypos
MouseMove, xpos, ypos
BlockInput, off
return
```

And even tried to wait once the shift is physically released, still no success;

```
+3::
SetMouseDelay, 0
MouseGetPos, xpos, ypos
KeyWait, +  
MouseClick, right, uhxpos, uhypos
Sleep, 41
MouseClick, left, yourxpos, yourypos
MouseMove, xpos, ypos
return
```

Would appreciate any help, thanks.

Comment: So, you are holding shift *while* you push `shiftf3`?  Or is it that you want the routine to run *after* you push `shiftf3` but despite the possibility that shift is held down?

Comment: Maybe you are going about this the wrong way.  What exactly are you trying to accomplish by tring to block `shift`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `KeyWait, Shift` instead of `KeyWait, +`

Answer (score 3):

Try to send {Shift Down} before {Shift Up} and maybe you should replace Send with SendInput:

```
+3::
  MouseGetPos, xpos, ypos
  SetMouseDelay, 0
  Sleep, 100
  SendInput, {Shift Down}
  SendInput, {Shift Up}
  MouseClick, right, uhxpos, uhypos
  Sleep, 41
  MouseClick, left, yourxpos, yourypos
  MouseMove, xpos, ypos
Return
```